# Chrome extension loses activeTab permission

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have an extension that, when the "browser action" (the icon next to the address bar) is clicked, executes a script on the current tab's page:

*background.js*

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    file: 'controls.js'
  });
});
```

The `controls.js` injects some stuff into the DOM so that the user can press a key to tell `background.js` to set up a WebRTC connection and do other business-logic stuff.

Usually this works just fine. But sometimes the extension stops working on a tab if it has been open but not used for a while, I think typically after the computer has gone to sleep and woken again. When this happens, in the console for `background.js`, I get the error "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access contents of the page. Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host."

Any idea why this could happen, or what I can do to catch this error and handle it to get permissions back?

Comment: Sounds like a bug which you can report on https://crbug.com if it's not reported already. To detect the error use the standard mechanism: check chrome.runtime.lastError in the callback of executeScript. See if reloading the tab helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a lot of futzing around to figure this out.

If the user has been idle for a while, upon refreshing the page, the website I'm injecting JS into will redirect to an authentication site on another domain, which will then redirect the user back. It happens fast enough to not notice typically, but Chrome removes the activeTab permission when the domain changes.

I'm handling the permission loss by notifying the user through the badge text, more or less like this:

```js
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
  code: 'alert("hello activeTab")'
}, (result) => {
  if (result === undefined) { // this means that activeTab permission is lost
    console.log('lost activeTab permission :(');
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
      text: 'off',
      tabId: tab.id
    });
  }
});
```